# webscraping hovarable menus, and load on scroll images with python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have been trying to webscrape this site one level deep, but when the scraping finishes the hoverable menus dont work, and lots of images remain blurry. The site only loads the non-blurry images when you scroll there and wait for them to load. Ive been trying to simulate this, but failed and dont know where it goes wrong.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import os
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import StaleElementReferenceException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

def scroll_to_bottom(driver):
    """
    Scrolls the page to the bottom slowly.
    """
    SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 1
    MAX_SCROLLS = 10
    SCROLL_INCREMENT = driver.execute_script("return window.innerHeight;")
    last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    scrolls = 0
    while scrolls < MAX_SCROLLS:
        driver.execute_script(f"window.scrollBy(0, {SCROLL_INCREMENT});")
        time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
        new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
        if new_height == last_height:
            break
        last_height = new_height
        scrolls += 1

def scrape_page(driver, url, directory, visited):
    """
    Scrapes a single page and saves it to the specified directory.
    """
    try:
        driver.get(url)
        scroll_to_bottom(driver)
        WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'body')))
        with open(f'{directory}/{url.replace("/", "-").replace("https:--www.classcentral.com-", "")}.html', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            f.write(driver.page_source)
            print(f"Scraped {url}")
            
        sub_links = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a')
        for sub_link in sub_links:
            try:
                sub_url = sub_link.get_attribute('href')
                if sub_url and 'classcentral.com' in sub_url and sub_url != url and sub_url not in visited:
                    sub_url = urljoin('https://www.classcentral.com/', sub_url)
                    visited.add(sub_url)
                    driver.get(sub_url)
                    scroll_to_bottom(driver)
                    scrape_page(driver, sub_url, directory, visited)
            except StaleElementReferenceException:
                continue
            time.sleep(10)
    except StaleElementReferenceException:
        pass

def scrape_site(url, max_depth):
    print("Scraping site...")
    """
    Scrapes the specified site up to a maximum depth.
    """
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get(url)
    WebDriverWait(driver, 40).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.TAG_NAME, 'body')))
    page_title = driver.title
    directory = f'classcentral-{page_title}'
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)
    
    visited = {url}
    print(f"Visited: {visited}")

    scrape_page(driver, url, directory, visited)
    
    queue = [(url, 1)]
    while queue:
        current_url, current_depth = queue.pop(0)
        if current_depth > max_depth:
            break
        driver.get(current_url)
        links = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'a, script[src]')
        for link in links:
            try:
                url = link.get_attribute('href') or link.get_attribute('src')
                if url and 'classcentral.com' in url and url not in visited and not url.startswith('mailto:'):
                    visited.add(url)
                    queue.append((url, current_depth + 1))
                    url = urljoin('https://www.classcentral.com/', url)
                    
                    scrape_page(driver, url, directory, visited)
            except StaleElementReferenceException:
                
                continue
    
    driver.quit()

scrape_site('https://www.classcentral.com/', 1)
```

Comment: Some hoverable menus use javascript and i think there is no way to let them work when you save the page. Even if you save the whole page (CTRL+S) the dropdown menu doesn't work. About the images there is a way to be sure that they are all loaded (not blurry) if you want I can write a partial answer about how to load the images